Engine about to stall while idling, every few seconds
For a few months now, my car (Volvo XC60 2015, 2.0 Diesel) has been showing the following symptoms:

when idling, the power briefly drops for a second, as if the engine is about to stall, then promptly returns to normal
this repeats every few seconds
while driving, everything seems normal, and I haven't noticed any power drops, so this only occurs when the engine is idle

This is a recording of the sound from under the hood. You’ll hear a low rumble start every few seconds, followed by a metallic click. Hopefully the spectrogram makes it easy to spot the rumble zones and the clicks:
https://youtu.be/VpK-oxnUsZs
Around the time the clicking happens, the power needle drops slightly, and the car vibrates due to low RPM. The clicks and rumble are only audible with the hood open; can't hear them from the inside of the car.

I took it to a service center, but no luck so far. They’ve replaced the following with no effect:

the inlet manifold with an actuator
a sensor on the fresh air pipe
the transmission kit

Any ideas what might be at fault?
Thanks!

It sounds like the rpm is rock-solid steady. If it were about to stall, the rpm would drop. Why do you say it is about to stall? Has it in fact stalled (ever?) when idling? Do you see the rpm change on the tach when it goes through these cycles of changing sound? This changing sound could be from the EGR opening and closing, perhaps inappropriately. Does this happen immediately from a cold start or only after it warms up? A lot of questions here, please answer all of them!

Thanks @MTA! I'll respond in 2 comments, because I exceeded the characters limit:

while this has been going on for months, the engine only stalled twice
I say it's about to stall because the power needle drops slightly (I edited the original post and added a picture of the dash) when that happens (which only lasts for a second), the car vibrates as if the RPM is below normal



I believe the power needle drops right at the moment when the click occurs in the recording (maybe that click is a mechanism that prevents the engine from stalling?); that click is preceded by a low rumble which I can only hear with the hood open (I can't hear it from the car)
usually it happens immediately from a cold start; the problem seems to ameliorate after driving for about 15-20 minutes

If it's the EGR, would that explain the rumble sound (I don't know how the EGR works)?

". . . the car vibrates as if the RPM is below normal . . ." but the RPM is not going below normal. Your illustration says "DOESN'T DROP" on the tach and your audio recording demonstrates that the RPM is completely steady, not dropping. So despite the title of your question, the engine is not in danger of stalling. The car vibration is the engine management system's instantaneous response to a changing load as indicated on your "power" gauge. That system holds your RPM steady at idle despite the changing "power" gauge. (I don't know why the car stalled twice in the last few months.)
I'm going out on a limb here, so fasten your seat belt.
I think the click is the glow plug relay, and the change in sound is caused by the extra load on the engine from the alternator providing power to run the glow plugs in a repeating on-off cycle while the engine is warming up.
I've owned several diesel vehicles, but no Volvo, and one thing they all had in common is that in cold weather the glow plugs (or intake air heater on non-glow plug diesels) operate for a few seconds before you start, then they operate intermittently after you start until the engine reaches a certain temperature.
The on-off glow plug cycle common to most diesels follows the same pattern as the change in sound of your engine. One of my diesel vehicles has a slight shudder/shake at the same moment that I hear the relay click while idling during the warmup phase, and the voltmeter on the instrument panel shows a voltage drop at the same time.
HOW TO TEST THE THEORY
You need a clamp-on DC ammeter like one of these:

(Photo credit: Google)
These are current prices in U.S. dollars, so you see there are some very inexpensive models out there. If you have no further use for one of these meters besides this test, feel free to get the cheapest one available in your market. You don't need high precision or reliability.
The test: Start with a cold engine on a cold day. Read the instructions on how to use the meter. Clamp the meter around the alternator's B+ wire, which is the thick, heavy wire on the alternator that goes directly to the battery. Make sure nothing will get caught in any engine belts, then start the car. Now go look at the meter. I think you will see the meter changing from a low reading (20 amps?) to a much higher reading (50+ amps?) every time you hear the click and the change in engine sound. If this is what you see, then the theory is confirmed.
ALTERNATE TEST
If you already have a digital voltmeter or multimeter and you don't want to buy a clamp-on DC ammeter, measure the battery voltage on the battery cable clamps, not on the battery posts, while the engine is cold and running. If you see the voltage rising and falling a lot (say 13-14V down to 10-12V) in cycles that coincide with the click and change of sound, this is indirect proof of the same phenomenon.
WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?
Maybe your battery is weak and can not provide supplemental power to help operate the glow plugs. You can have a mechanic do a load test on the battery.
Maybe you have corrosion on the battery terminals or a loose battery cable clamp. This can be repaired easily.
Please let us know what you find.
And if this is confirmed, and if you ever go back to that service center, you can ask them why they wasted your money on a transmission repair for an idling problem.

Thank you for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer! It all sounds very plausible indeed. I will find someone to help me test this theory.

@whonoes Very good! I'm looking forward to learning what you find when you run the test.
